# print Shortest sequence 1's in String

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, data-structures, sequence

```
class Chotu
 {
    // Returns length of the longest subsequence of 1's
    public static int ShortestSequence(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        int ans=s.length();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '1')
                count++;
            else
                count = 0;
            
            if(count < ans )
                ans=count;
        }
        return ans;
    }
    
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s =sc.next();
        if(ShortestSequence(s) > 1)
            System.out.println(ShortestSequence(s));
        else 
            System.out.println(-1);
    }
}
```

I'm making program to find shortest sequence of 1's in user input string. I had made program which gives me longest sequence need help.

Input : 11100011001
Output : 1

Comment: set `ans` to max number. Each iteration, if `count != 0`, set `ans = count if count < ans`

Comment: No it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the `String` and then use `stream`:

```
public static String shortestSequence(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("[^1]"))
        .filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
        .findFirst().orElse("");
}

public static String longestSequence(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("[^1]"))
        .filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed())
        .findFirst().orElse("");
}
```

Then:

```
String str = "11100011001";

System.out.println("Shortest: " + shortestSequence(str));
System.out.println("Longest: " + longestSequence(str));
```

Output:

```
Shortest: 1
Longest: 111
```